# iPhone 5C 8.1.2 iCloud Bypass or Forcible Downgrade

Tags: iphone, ios8, icloud

Is there a way to officially bypass the iCloud lock on 8.1.2 (iPhone 5C) devices, outside of Doulci? Something free, and does **not** require dialing 112? Apparently that's an emergency number.

I need this to continue development on iOS devices.

If not, is there a way or software to forcibly downgrade my iOS version to 7.1.2, or an early hackable iOS 8 firmware without iTunes? I own a Macbook Pro, running Yosemite, if that makes it easier. I have access to a Windows machine too.

This is a legitimate question, and it's not a duplicate from the last one I had made asking for Doulci specifics. Please do not lock this unless the question becomes dead, I don't know how to contact people and ask why the questions are "Deleted". I don't understand why my last question (which was all about Doulci) was locked. I really believe this would be useful for other iOS developers who don't have $500 on hand.

Thanks! :)

Comment: The question seems potentially on-topic to me, but there may be precedent that says otherwise - I don't follow the iFoo tags, and each community has its own precedents.  If a question is closed or deleted and you don't understand why, you can ask on [Stack Overflow Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).  I've removed the "windows" tag because the question isn't really about Windows, and because it may attract readers who will vote to close because they don't see any relationship to programming.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the Activation Lock, then I really count on there being no way around it since IOS 8.

If you load a different os on it (i.e. jail break it) then you may have some joy, for a while, but you will need the password to get IOS 8 back on it.

The best way is to turn off find my iPhone, using the password.

If no password then you can reset the password if you have the security answers required. last resort call apple support.

Comment: The software I've found doesn't offer a way around the iCloud. It keeps wanting to have the  Find my iPhone and/or iCloud disabled before it does anything. Pangu and some other company (sounded like a Tiger name) looked promising but I saw nothing else potential to jailbreak it even.

Comment: Yep, it is a pretty looking brick - or you tell the NSA that it used to Edward Snowdon's if you really have to have it unlocked.

Comment: What is an Edward Snowdon?

Comment: I might have a good idea, going rouge on my own analysis, but I am not a born bred hacker... I guess I'll toy with it a little longer before I say anything.

It's a pretty green brick too as of now. xD

Comment: Edward Snowdon, far to ******** to discuss here

Answer (score 0):

Only working ways to unlock/bypass iCloud at current moment:

1. Ask previous owner to remove it from their iCloud account
2. Get previous owner iCloud account control in not legit ways/phishing
3. If it Clean mode than find legit Apple Employee who will remove it by GSX account request
4. If it Lost mode, than there is no other ways than 1 or 2 steps of this list
5. If device still works but linked to iCloud, use myicloud info trick to restore backup from working device. Full bypass until first firmware restoring
6. I have develop server that gives access to web browser - iCloud DNS Bypass, it free and works for all iOS versions. So it only bypass working at current moment, but no calls and no mobile Internet.

Answer (score 0):

The only way at the moment is to Erase the SSD nand Completely which the device Has Security measures for keeping you from doing so. Thus the SSD nand would have to be replaced, then restored with IOS version you wish to install.

Comment: a 16Gb Nand will cost around $7 US plus shipping and go up to 128Gb for $70 US plus Shipping